# Adding another Kubernetes cluster to Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, kubernetes-helm

I have already added a Kubernetes cluster to my project in Gitlab. The cluster is hosted on AWS. This configuration works fine and I am able to deploy my apps. I want to add another Kubernetes cluster that is also hosted on AWS but in a different region to the same project. So far I am unable to find a way to add another cluster to the same project. Gitlab doesn't give me the option to add another cluster. Is it possible? And if it is possible how should I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only in Gitlab Enterprise Edition. [Support for multiple Kubernetes clusters](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#multiple-kubernetes-clusters-premium) was introduced in [Gitlab Premium/Ultimate](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/self-managed/feature-comparison/) 10.3.

> With GitLab Premium, you can associate more than one Kubernetes
>   clusters to your project. That way you can have different clusters for
>   different environments, like dev, staging, production, etc.
>
> Simply add another cluster, like you did the first time, and make sure
>   to set an environment scope that will differentiate the new cluster
>   with the rest.